# Blazor .Net Task.Whenall() Will Stock

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, task, blazor-webassembly

guys.

I have a question is I use Blazor to do sync mall products and track the sync task.
I created two Task

1. Task syncMallProductTask  --> do synctask 
   **public async Task syncMallProductTask(args...)**
2. Task progressCheckTask  --> to long pooling track progress 
   **public async Task<ActionResult> GetProgress(string SyncGuid)**

Then use `await Task.WhenAll()` to run those, and do something after the Task finish.

But it will stock on Task.Whenall, I try to write log in those fuction's, I sure they have done all the work, my log is last line.

but the main Task have something to do after Task.WhenAll(), but it will not to do.

under is main function

```
public async Task SyncBtnClick()

{

    string SyncId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
    ProductSuccessCount = 0;
    GetItemListDto = await ProductService.GetItemList(MallId);
    ProductCount = GetItemListDto.Response.TotalCount;
    SyncState=false;
    await ModalSync.Show();

    Task syncMallProductTask = Task.Run(async () =>
    {
        await ProductService.SyncMallProduct(SyncId, MallId);
    });

    Task progressCheckTask = Task.Run(async () =>
    {
        while (ProductSuccessCount < ProductCount)
        {
            await Task.Delay(3000);
            ProductSuccessCount = await _http.GetFromJsonAsync<int>("api/Product/GetProgress?SyncGuid=" + SyncId);
            StateHasChanged();
        }
        
    });
    await Task.WhenAll(syncMallProductTask, progressCheckTask);   <---- Will Stock at here    

    // 检查任务的完成情况
    if (syncMallProductTask.IsFaulted)
    {
        // 处理syncMallProductTask任务的异常
        Log.Warning("syncMallProductTask任務出現異常: " + syncMallProductTask.Exception);
    }
    else if (progressCheckTask.IsFaulted)
    {
        // 处理progressCheckTask任务的异常
        Log.Warning("progressCheckTask任務出現異常: " + progressCheckTask.Exception);
    }
    else
    {
        // 子任务成功完成后执行的操作
        Log.Information("子任務已完成");

        SyncState=true;
        
        await Task.Delay(3000); //等待3秒，讓資料庫完全寫入再讀取
        await MallService.MallsSyncInitList();
        Mall = MallService.Malls.ToList();
        StateHasChanged();
    }
}
```

Comment: You don't need all of those `Task.Run`s. An `async` method *already* returns a `Task` that you can `await`.

Comment: Without knowing the inners of what goes on in the two tasks, I cannot be certain, but I would say that eventually, deep in the code, one task depends on the other.  Since Blazor has a single-threaded synchronization context, a deadlock occurs.  One quick way to get out of this is to use ConfigureAwait(false) in one of the tasks so another thread picks it up, but it must not attempt to update the UI.

Comment: @DanielMann Yes, I understand that in .Net it is recommended to use awiat instead of using Task.Run, but I want SyncTask to execute without waiting at the beginning, so should I remove Task.Run and call him without await?

Comment: @JoséRamírez The reason why I don't want to show the deep code is that it is very verbose, but I can still show it if necessary. As for the method you mentioned, I may try it later, thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

If I'm reading this correctly, you can simplify your `SyncBtnClick`.  You don't need the task run stuff.  Unless you're running processor intensive code, you can run everything on the UI thread.

```cs
public async Task SyncBtnClick() 
{
    //...
    
    var syncMailTask = ProductService.SyncMallProduct(SyncId, MallId);
    var checkSuccessTask = CheckSuccessAsync();

    await Task.WhenAll(new Task[] { syncMailTask, checkSuccessTask});

    //... The rest


}

private async Task CheckSuccessAsync()
{
        while (ProductSuccessCount < ProductCount)
        {
            await Task.Delay(3000);
            ProductSuccessCount = await _http.GetFromJsonAsync<int>("api/Product/GetProgress?SyncGuid=" + SyncId);
            StateHasChanged();
        }
}
```

However, for this code to complete `CheckSuccessAsync` needs to complete.

Comment: Thank you, I will try your method and reply with the result.